# Какие есть способы запуска локального Html файла в WebView? (UWP)

Tags: c#, html, uwp, webview

У меня есть однострочный ХТМЛ файл в который нужно программно подставить ссылку на файл и открыть в ВебВью. Проблема в том что я не знаю куда его положить. если файл лежит в папке Assets(или вложенной в неё) не получается записать в него данные(говорит отказано в доступе), если лежит в LocalState(или вложенной в нее)то можно его изменять но открыть его не получается ВебВью как будто не видит файла.

```
WebView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/page.html");//в такомм виде все открывается, но не возможно изменить файл
WebView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///LocalState/page.html");//в такомм виде можно редактировать, но открыть не получается(я думаю что это неправильный адрес)
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, формат локального адреса не верен.

Получить из локального хранилища можно вот так:

```
WebView.Source = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/page.html")
```